# C# find when file was uploaded on FTP

Tags: c#, file, datetime, ftp, upload

I have a job that once in a set periods of time "looks" at FTP if some new files have been uploaded. Once it finds any, it downloads it. 
The question is how using C# to extract the time when the file was actually uploaded to FTP.

Thank you. I just still can't figure out how to extract exactly the time when file was uploaded to FTP, not modified. As the following shows the time of file modification.

```
fileInfo = session.GetFileInfo(FileFullPath);
dateUploaded = fileInfo.LastWriteTime;
```

Please advice some sample code that may be integrated in my current solution

```
using (Session session = new Session())
 {
    string FileFullPath = 
        Dts.Variables["User::FTP_FileFullPath"].Value.ToString();                                               
    session.Open(sessionOptions);                                                                   
    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;                                                              
    session.MoveFile(FileFullPath, newFTPFullPath);                          
    TransferOperationResult transferResult;
    transferResult = session.GetFiles(newFTPFullPath,                                 
        Dts.Variables["User::Local_DownloadFolder"].Value.ToString(),false);                                    
    Dts.Variables["User::FTP_FileProcessDate"].Value = dateTime; 
}
```

Comment: Do you keep downloaded files locally and remotely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might not be able to, unless you know the FTP server reliably sets the file create/modified date to the date it was uploaded. Do some test uploads and see. If it works out for you on this particular server you want to use then great; keep a note of when you last visited and retrieve files with a greater date. By way of an example, a test upload to an Azure ftp server just now (probably derived from Microsoft IIS) did indeed set the time of the file to the datetime it was uploaded. Beware that the listed file time sent by the server might not be the same timezone as you are in, nor will it have any timezone info represented - it could just be some number of hours out relative to your current time

To get the date itself you'll need to parse the response the server gives you when you list the remote directory. If you're using an FTP library for C# **(edit: you're using WinSCP)**, that might already be handled for you **(edit: it is, see https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_listdirectory and https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_remotefileinfo)**; unless things have improved recently the default FTP provision in .NET isn't great - it's more intended for basic file retrieval than complex syncing, so i'd definitely look at using a capable library (and we don't do software recs here, sorry, so I can't recommend one) if you're scrutinizing the date info offered

That said, there's another way to carry out this sync process that is more of a side effect of what you want to do (and doesn't necessarily rely on parsing a non standard list output) overall as a process:

Keep a memory of every file you saw last time and reference it when looking at every file that is there now. This is actually quite easy to do:

- Download all the files.
- Disconnect.
- Go back some time later and download any files that you don't already have
- Keep track of which files you downloaded and do something with them?

You say you want to download them anyway, so just treat any file you don't already have (or maybe one that has a newer date, different file size etc) as one that is new/changed since you last looked

Big job, potentially, depending how many various servers you want to support

Comment: Thank you. I just still can't figure out how to extract exactly the time when file was uploaded to FTP, not modified. As the following shows the time of file modification

Comment: I'm not sure how to interpret your comment. It appears to be a statement of fact, with no call to action, and doesn't add any more information than what has already been posted, so I'm not sure what response you are seeking.

Comment: Please look at the updated question description. Too much text for comment field

Comment: Your edited question text posts some code, but that code doesn't contain a call to ListDirectory https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_listdirectory (or enumeratefiles).. My answer *did* say that you'd have to list the remote directory and get the file dates. Listing the directory gives you a Files collection of type https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_remotefileinfo RemoteFileInfo, that has the last modified date

Comment: You should also read https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_synchronizedirectories

Comment: Yeah, I understand what you're talking about. I didn't use RemoteDirectoryInfo I used RemoteFileInfo straight away as the path and file name already known.     RemoteFileInfo fileInfo;                                                                                             fileInfo = session.GetFileInfo(ManifestFileFullPath);
dateUploaded = fileInfo.LastWriteTime;                                                               And I get date but it's not the date I need. It returns 7-th November, when the file was last modified. But I've uploaded it on FTP today, and I want this date

Comment: Yeah, I see. But I can't understand how to fetch Time from using the method SynchronizeDirectories. I write                                                                                     SynchronizationResult sync;                              sync = Session.SynchronizeDirectories(SynchronizationMode.Remote, Dts.Variables["User::Local_DownloadFolder"].Value.ToString(), Dts.Variables["User::FileFTPPath"].Value.ToString(),false, false, SynchronizationCriteria.Time, null);                                                                          however it gives compilation errors ((

Comment: *And I get date but it's not the date I need. It returns 7-th November, when the file was last modified. But I've uploaded it on FTP today, and I want this date* - what's the very first sentence in my answer above?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You mean that there might not be an option to do so, right? "You might not be able to, unless you know the FTP server reliably sets the file create/modified date to the date it was uploaded.". And yes, I tried session.GetFileInfo(FileFullPath).LastWriteTime but unfortunately out FTP server doesn't set the file date to the date it was uploaded (( Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you change the FTP server software to one that does? Or change the system out entirely, and use some alternative sync system